# Using the LIMIT function to display the 1st, 2nd and 3rd row, with the MAX customer rating using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to display the 1st, 2nd and 3rd names in the table with the highest customer rating. I created done the following query:

This query display the 1st, 2nd and 3rd names in the table,

```
SELECT *
FROM donuts
WHERE customer_rating
LIMIT 1,3;
```

I tried to use the MAX function to get the 3 highest customer ratings but I get a blank table.

```
SELECT MAX(customer_rating), donutName
FROM donuts
WHERE customer_rating
LIMIT 1,3;
```

Any suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT *
FROM donuts
ORDER BY customer_rating DESC
LIMIT 0, 3
```

The reason you got an empty result is because `LIMIT 1, 3` prints the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th entries, not the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd entries, because `LIMIT` is zero-based (unlike just about everything else in SQL). But when you use an aggregate function like `MAX()` you only get one row of results (all the results are combined into a single maximum), so there is no 2nd entry.

Comment: That makes sense, I wasn't aware the MAX function wasn't able to output multiple entries. Thank you very much for the help.